# PostgreSQL window function & difference between dates

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

Suppose I have data formatted in the following way (FYI, total row count is over 30K):

```
customer_id             order_date  order_rank
A                       2017-02-19  1
A                       2017-02-24  2
A                       2017-03-31  3
A                       2017-07-03  4
A                       2017-08-10  5
B                       2016-04-24  1
B                       2016-04-30  2
C                       2016-07-18  1
C                       2016-09-01  2
C                       2016-09-13  3
```

I need a 4th column, let's call it `days_since_last_order` which, in the case where order_rank = 1 then 0 else calculate the number of days since the previous order (with rank n-1).

So, the above would return:

```
customer_id             order_date  order_rank  days_since_last_order
A                       2017-02-19  1           0
A                       2017-02-24  2           5
A                       2017-03-31  3           35
A                       2017-07-03  4           94
A                       2017-08-10  5           38
B                       2016-04-24  1           0
B                       2016-04-30  2           6
C                       2016-07-18  1           79
C                       2016-09-01  2           45
C                       2016-09-13  3           12
```

Is there an easier way to calculate the above with a window function (or similar) rather than join the entire dataset against itself (eg. on A.order_rank = B.order_rank - 1) and doing the calc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

use the lag window function

```
SELECT 
  customer_id
, order_date
, order_rank
, COALESCE(
  DATE(order_date) 
    - DATE(LAG(order_date) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date)) 
  , 0)
FROM <table_name>
```

Comment: `order by order_date DESC` ?

Comment: no, ordering should be ascending in this case because i'm `lag`ging  and not `lead`ing